# Firebase Security Rule to give multiple users access is not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement a Firebase Security Rule to give users access to a "Project" document.
I have a collection of projects and each project has a members collection with the UserIDs.
The User is authenticated.

My structure looks like this : 
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9zbH.png)

This is my Security Rule, but it's not working.
Can anyone help me ?   What am I doing wrong ?

//Firebase Rule

```
    rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /projects/{projectID} {
            allow read, get, write: if request.auth.uid != null && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/{project}/members/$(request.auth.uid));
        }
  }
}
```

//Flutter Call

```
Stream<List<ProjectModel>> getUserList() {
    print("getUSer");
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('projects').snapshots().map(
        (snapShot) => snapShot.docs
            .map((document) => ProjectModel(
                name: document.data()['name'],
                owner: document.data()['owner'],
                description: document.data()['description']))
            .toList());
  }
```

Comment: What is your query? Are you authenticated? The structure you shows seems to mix collection and document field, can you be clearer about which one is a collection?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my question. It should be clear now.

Comment: See New Update of my answer .. Wish that work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Example :

Authenticated User that can read or write to Projects Collection :

```
rules_version = '2';
   service cloud.firestore {
     match /databases/{database}/documents {
       match /projects/{projectID} {
         allow read, write: if request.auth != null && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/{projectID}/members/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
  }
}
```

**Note** : Inside Your Members Collection The Documents inside it must be Auth .uid Like the following Photo
[image: Projects Collection]

[image: Auth.Uid]

Comment: For sure this is working, but this is not what I need.

Comment: @ThiemoImgraben Sorry .. But you need Security Rule that give user access to Project Document .. Please Explain Why to update my answer .. Thanks

Comment: Hey Kevin, thank you for your input, but the Members Collection is inside the the project document.

Comment: @ThiemoImgraben .. Did it work? .. Or still have problems ?

Comment: Hey Kevin, thank you for your input, but the Members Collection is inside the the project document. I think the problem is that I need to change the Flutter call, because it needs to be the same as the rule

Comment: You can edit the Rules to match your project .. But I just give you Idea about that .. You can send me Screenshoot as the above image for you DB Structure .. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I uploaded a screenshot. The members Collection has documents in it, and the documentIDs are the userIDs.

Comment: Thanks for the update. There is still the problem, that the data fetch from the app needs to match the security rule. And I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @ThiemoImgraben I think your Rules are ready .. Test your Project Now .. But as I noted inside Members Collection is Documant So this document Title must be Auth.uid the if the User match So he have access to Project :)

Comment: @ThiemoImgraben Sounds Like new Problem .. I recommend to post it to Stack Overflow .. I wish I helped you .. Good Luck